# Query ElasticSearch from C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, httpwebrequest

Im very new to elasticsearch so this might be a very simple error.
Im trying to get elasticsearch to tell me how many debug statements have been logged within 15minunts

I have used Kibana to generate the JSON, which looks like this

```
    {
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "level:debug",
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": 1482481509040,
                  "lte": 1482482409040
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {}
}
```

I have created this method in my C# class

```
public void CallElasticSearch()
{

var    json = "{ {\"size\": 0,\"query\": {\"filtered\": {\"query\": {\"query_string\": {\"query\": \"level:debug\",\"analyze_wildcard\": true}},\"filter\": {\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"range\": {\"@timestamp\": {\"gte\": 1482481509040,\"lte\": 1482482409040}}}],\"must_not\": []}}}},\"aggs\": {}}";


            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://myElasticSearch:9200/serilog/_search"));
            request.Timeout = 600 * 1000; //10 minutes
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            using (var webStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                webStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
            try
            {
                var webResponse = request.GetResponse();

                using (var webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (webStream != null)
                    {
                        using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
                        {
                            string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                            return response;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Webstream is null");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                if (e.InnerException != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
                throw e;
            }


        }
```

When debugging I get an exception when executing `var webResponse = request.GetResponse();` I get this exception: `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.`

If i enter http://myElasticSearch:9200/serilog/_search into a browser i get

```
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

Comment: Your JSON string is invalid. That being said, why are you using the archaic HttpWebRequest (use HttpClient), or rather, why aren't you using the Elasticsearch.NET API?

Comment: @CodeCaster Actually i wasnt aware of a .net API. Which one shoud I go for, the ElasticSearch.net or the NEST.